# Output of array values with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I'm using react to get a JSON feed of MLB scores, and I keep getting stuck. My original JSON, looked to a specific game and output its values ([Working JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9y4zp1g1/1/)) and its all fine and dandy. But What I really want to accomplish is outputting values from ALL the games. The JSON "tree" is as follows, `data.games.game[0].your_value` so I want to be able to grab any values from each game and output them. What I came up with was:

```
    var scoreFeed;

var scoreBox = React.createClass({
  render: function(){

      var gameDetails = $.each(scoreFeed, function(i,v){
        return <div className="game-detail">{v.home_team_name}</div>;
      })


    return <div><h2>Game</h2>{gameDetails}</div>;
  }
});

var MLBScores = React.createClass({
  updateUI(props){
    this.serverRequest = $.get(props.feed, function(result){
      scoreFeed = JSON.parse(result).data.games.game;
    })
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.updateUI(this.props);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
    this.updateUI(newProps);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
    console.log('Aborted.');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <scoreBox />
    );
  }
});

function render(){
  ReactDOM.render( < MLBScores feed= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erwstout/pinetar/develop/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json" / > ,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}

setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Scores were rendered.')
  render();
}, 30000);
render();
```

([link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y4zp1g1/3/))
But this returns nothing. No console errors or anything. When I originally thought of how to build this out I thought I could output multiple children components, but apparently thats not supported.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**:
I've changed the initial code a bit, but its still not working

JSX:

```
var ScoreBox = React.createClass({
  render: function(){

     var gameDetails = $.each(this.props.scoreFeed, function(i,v){
        var homeTeam = v.home_team_name;
        return <div>{homeTeam}</div>;
      }); 



    return(
        <div>
        <h2>Games</h2>
        {gameDetails}
       </div>
    ); 
  }
});

var GameScores = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     scoreFeed: []
   }
  },

    updateUI(props){
    this.serverRequest = $.get(props.scoreFeed, function(result){
      var scoreFeed = JSON.parse(result).data.games.game;
      this.setState({scoreFeed: scoreFeed});
    }.bind(this))
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.updateUI(this.props);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
    this.updateUI(newProps);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
    console.log('Aborted.');
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Todays Games</h1>
        <ScoreBox />
      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <GameScores scoreFeed="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erwstout/pinetar/develop/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Or you can view an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erwstout/dnowLws9/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data down to the component via props NOT set a global variable outside of the components scope:

```
var scoreBox = React.createClass({
  render: function(){

      var gameDetails = $.each(this.props.scoreFeed, function(i,v){
        return <div className="game-detail">{v.home_team_name}</div>;
      })


    return <div><h2>Game</h2>{gameDetails}</div>;
  }
});

var MLBScores = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     scoreFeed: []
   }
  }

  // Update as suggested by @wintvelt 
  updateUI(props){
    this.serverRequest = $.get(props.feed, function(result){
      var scoreFeed = JSON.parse(result).data.games.game;
      this.setState({scoreFeed: scoreFeed});
    }.bind(this))
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.updateUI(this.props);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
    this.updateUI(newProps);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
    console.log('Aborted.');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <scoreBox scoreFeed={this.state.scoreFeed} />
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Agree with your answer. But if you do `var state = this.state;` and later `state.scorefeed = JSON.parse(...);` then you directly mutate `this.state`. Which is not a good idea.

Comment: `var state= this.state` does not copy the object, only the pointer to the object. So `state.scorefeed = x` also results in `this.state.scorefeed = x`. Proof in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/GZBWbr?editors=0012) The need for `setState() ` exists because react needs to do a lot of stuff around changing the variable `this.state` - such as firing all lifecycle events.

Comment: @wintvelt Yes sir, my apologies you are right...I have updated my answer with your advise in mind....;)

Comment: Thank you! Your overall point to not use global variable still holds.

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I try your answer in a JSFiddle, it still doesn't output any values. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you send me a link to the fiddle?

Comment: @deowk heres an updated fiddle i was trying, i feel like its really close but its still not outputting each value for the home team. https://jsfiddle.net/erwstout/dnowLws9/5/

Answer (score 0):

Fix needed to get output at all:

- your component needs to be capitalized: Should be `<ScoreBox/>` instead of `<scoreBox>`. With lowercase, JSX turns `<scoreBox/>` into an HTML element, instead of your react component.

Other recommendations:

- Do NOT put your `ReactDOM.render()` in an interval timeout. This is a very, very bad idea. Instead, manage your time interval within your react component. Better is to put your data-fetch in a time interval inside your root-react-component.
- Do not use global variable for scorefeed (as mentioned in @deowk's answer).
- I would suggest to move one `updateUI()` call from `componentWillReceiveProps()` to `componentDidUpdate()`. This makes your code more consistent. Then `updateUI()` is always called AFTER your render.

Then you can simply set a timeout to make the call to server. React already creates a cycle (endless loop actually) if you have a `setState()` inside `componentDidUpdate()`. Because `setState()` triggers `render()`, which is then followed by `componentDidUpdate()`, etc.

Then `updateUI()` would look something like this (also avoid mutating state directly):

```
updateUI(props){
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.serverRequest = $.get(props.feed, function(result){
      var scoreFeed = JSON.parse(result).data.games.game;
      self.setState(scoreFeed);
    });
  }, 60000);
```

Comment: Would moving the interval into the `updateUI` still auto update the scores if there are changes? Thats why the render was called in an interval so that the user would not have to refresh. Thanks for the advice, this is my first jump into ReactJS.

Comment: Yes it would. The `ReactDOM.render()` is really only meant to start your react engine. Once started, you manage your cycles from within react.

Comment: The cycle is `render()` => `componentDidMount()` (first time) or `componentDidUpdate()` (second time and onward) => `updateUI()`, which contains `setState()`, which fires next `render()`, and so on.

Comment: Come to think of it: you do not even need the interval. React has its own (untimed) cycle.

Comment: Is there documentation I can find on setting the cycle though? I'd like to have it fetch the scores every 45 or 60 seconds, or does it automatically know when the external JSON file gets updates?

Comment: You can set the cycle by using timeout instead of interval. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to do some testing when I get home from the office and see what I can come up with.